# Debootstrap debian into root with SW RAID1

Tags: debian, raid, arm, debootstrap

I'm stuck with a Linux upgrade question, please give me some advice for the following situation:

I've a NAS with Marvell Armada 370 CPU which runs an ancient Debian (Etch, I believe). The NAS itself has 4 disks, and for the root partition (and boot also, swap also) all the four disks are in a RAID1 configuration.

**In detail:**

```
4 disks: sda, sdb, sdc, sdd

Partitions: sda1,sda2,sda3,sda4,sda5,sda6 (and all the same for sdb,sdc,sdd).

Boot RAID1: sda1,sdb1,sdc1,sdd1

RootFS RAID1: sda2,sdb2,sdc2,sdd2

Unknown: 3,4 partitions

Storage: 5,6 partitions
```

**Now the problem:** I'd like to have a more recent Debian on this device. Current one doesn't have apt, nor gcc. Also, it's an arm architecture, and I can't find any packages with arm (but armel, which is now not compatible because of Etch). The device does not have serial console. So the first point of contact is when SSHD is up.

**Goal:** To have a current Debian installed onto the rootfs.

How would you do this guys? I have fair Linux knowledge. Debootstrap could be one method I guess. But still, I need to add sshd onto that, and somehow I also need to upload to the device. (Anyway, is "debootstrap lenny /" reasonable on a running machine? I wasn't that brave to test.)